# Finding number of months between overlapping periods - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the data set of customers with their policies, I am trying to find the number of months the customer is with us. (tenure)

df

```
cust_no poly_no start_date  end_date
1       1       2016-06-01   2016-08-31
1       2       2017-05-01   2018-05-31
1       3       2016-11-01   2018-05-31
```

output should look like,

```
cust_no no_of_months
1        22
```

So basically, it should get rid of the months where there is no policy and count the overlapping period once not twice. I have to do this for every customers, so group by cust_no, how can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple customers you can use `groupby`. Continuing with [@ScottBoston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732064/10466556):

```
df_range = df.apply(lambda r: pd.Series(
                    pd.date_range(start=r.start_date, end=r.end_date, freq='M')
                    .values), axis=1)
df_range.groupby('cust_no').apply(lambda x: x.stack().unique().shape[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create date ranges for each records, then use stack to get all the months.  Next, take the unique values only to count a month only once:

```
s = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.start_date, x.end_date, freq='M').values), axis=1)
ss = s.stack().unique()
ss.shape[0]
```

Output:

```
22
```

Comment: Thanks. How can we do that as a dataframe? For multiple customers?